# Получение определённого значения из JSON ссылки

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Здравствуйте. Как можно, с помощью JavaScript получить определенно значение из JSON (https://data.egov.kz/api/v2/valutalar_bagamdary4/v149?pretty)?

Например из этого JSON ссылки, мне нужно значение курса валюты тенге к доллару ("id" : "12"). В данный момент оно ровняется 337.04 тг.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

```js
var money = [ {
  "id" : "2",
  "name_kaz" : "ӘЗЕРБАЙЖАН МАНАТЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "АЗЕРБАЙДЖАНСКИЙ МАНАТ",
  "kurs" : "201.82",
  "kod" : "AZN"
}, {
  "id" : "7",
  "name_kaz" : "ОҢТҮСТІК КОРЕЯ РЕСПУБЛИКАСЫНЫҢ ВОНАСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "100",
  "name_rus" : "ВОНА РЕСПУБЛИКИ ЮЖНАЯ КОРЕЯ",
  "kurs" : "29.96",
  "kod" : "KRW"
}, {
  "id" : "12",
  "name_kaz" : "АҚШ ДОЛЛАРЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "ДОЛЛАР США",
  "kurs" : "337.04",
  "kod" : "USD"
}, {
  "id" : "16",
  "name_kaz" : "КАНАДА ДОЛЛАРЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "КАНАДСКИЙ ДОЛЛАР ",
  "kurs" : "266.88",
  "kod" : "CAD"
}, {
  "id" : "21",
  "name_kaz" : "МЕКСИКА ПЕСОСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "МЕКСИКАНСКИЙ ПЕСО",
  "kurs" : "18.96",
  "kod" : "MXN"
}, {
  "id" : "26",
  "name_kaz" : "САУД АРАБИЯ РИЯЛЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "РИЯЛ САУДОВСКОЙ АРАВИИ ",
  "kurs" : "89.87",
  "kod" : "SAR"
}, {
  "id" : "31",
  "name_kaz" : "ТҮРІК ЛИРАСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "ТУРЕЦКАЯ ЛИРА",
  "kurs" : "97.33",
  "kod" : "TRY"
}, {
  "id" : "36",
  "name_kaz" : "ШВЕД КРОНАСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "ШВЕДСКАЯ КРОНА",
  "kurs" : "42.18",
  "kod" : "SEK"
}, {
  "id" : "1",
  "name_kaz" : "АВСТРАЛИЯ ДОЛЛАРЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "1",
  "name_rus" : "АВСТРАЛИЙСКИЙ ДОЛЛАР ",
  "kurs" : "265.82",
  "kod" : "AUD"
}, {
  "id" : "6",
  "name_kaz" : "ВЕНГРИЯ ФОРИНТІ",
  "edinica_izmerenia" : "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie" : "10",
  "name_rus" : "ВЕНГЕРСКИЙ ФОРИНТ",
  "kurs" : "13.07",
  "kod" : "HUF"
} ];

for(var i in money) {
  if(money[i].id == 12) console.log(money[i].kurs)
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! В переменную money вы добавили готовые JSON строки из ссылки, что я прикрепил. А где и как указывать сам JSON ссылку? Я ранее пользовался с $.getJSON(), но оно почему то не считывает данные именно из этой json ссылки.

Answer (score 0):

Могу предложить универсальную функцию, которая будет искать курс по введенной валюте (как на русском, так и на казахском):

```js
var rates = [{
  "id": "2",
  "name_kaz": "ӘЗЕРБАЙЖАН МАНАТЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "АЗЕРБАЙДЖАНСКИЙ МАНАТ",
  "kurs": "201.82",
  "kod": "AZN"
}, {
  "id": "7",
  "name_kaz": "ОҢТҮСТІК КОРЕЯ РЕСПУБЛИКАСЫНЫҢ ВОНАСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "100",
  "name_rus": "ВОНА РЕСПУБЛИКИ ЮЖНАЯ КОРЕЯ",
  "kurs": "29.96",
  "kod": "KRW"
}, {
  "id": "12",
  "name_kaz": "АҚШ ДОЛЛАРЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "ДОЛЛАР США",
  "kurs": "337.04",
  "kod": "USD"
}, {
  "id": "16",
  "name_kaz": "КАНАДА ДОЛЛАРЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "КАНАДСКИЙ ДОЛЛАР ",
  "kurs": "266.88",
  "kod": "CAD"
}, {
  "id": "21",
  "name_kaz": "МЕКСИКА ПЕСОСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "МЕКСИКАНСКИЙ ПЕСО",
  "kurs": "18.96",
  "kod": "MXN"
}, {
  "id": "26",
  "name_kaz": "САУД АРАБИЯ РИЯЛЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "РИЯЛ САУДОВСКОЙ АРАВИИ ",
  "kurs": "89.87",
  "kod": "SAR"
}, {
  "id": "31",
  "name_kaz": "ТҮРІК ЛИРАСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "ТУРЕЦКАЯ ЛИРА",
  "kurs": "97.33",
  "kod": "TRY"
}, {
  "id": "36",
  "name_kaz": "ШВЕД КРОНАСЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "ШВЕДСКАЯ КРОНА",
  "kurs": "42.18",
  "kod": "SEK"
}, {
  "id": "1",
  "name_kaz": "АВСТРАЛИЯ ДОЛЛАРЫ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "1",
  "name_rus": "АВСТРАЛИЙСКИЙ ДОЛЛАР ",
  "kurs": "265.82",
  "kod": "AUD"
}, {
  "id": "6",
  "name_kaz": "ВЕНГРИЯ ФОРИНТІ",
  "edinica_izmerenia": "ТЕНГЕ",
  "sootnowenie": "10",
  "name_rus": "ВЕНГЕРСКИЙ ФОРИНТ",
  "kurs": "13.07",
  "kod": "HUF"
}];

function showRate(name) {
  for (var i in rates) {
    if (rates[i].name_rus == name || rates[i].name_kaz == name) return rates[i].kurs
  }
}

console.log(showRate('ДОЛЛАР США')); // rus
console.log(showRate('АҚШ ДОЛЛАРЫ')); // kaz
console.log(showRate('АЗЕРБАЙДЖАНСКИЙ МАНАТ')); // rus
console.log(showRate('ӘЗЕРБАЙЖАН МАНАТЫ')); // kaz
console.log(showRate('ВЕНГЕРСКИЙ ФОРИНТ')); // rus
console.log(showRate('ВЕНГРИЯ ФОРИНТІ')); // kaz
```

Comment: Спасибо! А через какую функцию можно добавить данные из json ссылки в переменную rates? Вы добавили готовые JSON строки из ссылки, что я прикрепил. Мне нужно вставить JSON ссылку, потому что данные (курсы валют), меняется чуть ли не каждую минуту.

Comment: @AltynbekKazezov Это уже отдельный вопрос. Распарсить ссылку можно методами $.getJSON() или $.ajax(). Здесь, к сожалению, не получится продемонстрировать, т.к. источник (по ссылке) запрещает кроссдоменные запросы.

Comment: $.getJSON() пробовал, выдает ошибку. Можете написать мне ваше решение в skype (altinbek-_97), или где вам удобно?
@Cheg

Comment: @AltynbekKazezov ошибка как раз из-за кроссдоменного запроса. вам нужно зарегистрироваться на data.egov.kz и получить доступ к api, чтобы можно было выполнять ajax запросы к данным этого сервиса

Comment: На портале написано, что "Для того чтобы найти, посмотреть, скачать открытые данные и приложения на их основе, а также данные в разделе «Архив» Вам не требуется авторизация на портале."
@Cheg

Comment: @AltynbekKazezov одно дело зайти через браузер посмотреть или скачать, и совсем другое - в одном приложении парсить динамически обновляемые данные с другого источника. Для этого и нужен API

Comment: @AltynbekKazezov если мой ответ помог решить вашу проблемы, вы можете отметить его принятым, нажав на галочку рядом с ним